# How to Access Private Member Data of a Passed in Template Parameter

Tags: c++, templates

working on adding a custom comparator function similar to how set is, but doing it as a passed in template parameter. In order to test if this works I have a constructor that is made using this template parameter object as an argument and setting a private member of the same type to the passed in argument. How do I access the private member declared in the class that will be passed in as the template parameter?

Here's the necessary code:

`template <typename T,class Comparator = std::less<T>> class square_list`

`private: Comparator m_cmp; // The private object within my container class`

`square_list(Comparator const& cmp) : m_cmp(cmp) { if (m_cmp.mode == 1) data_.sort(); } \\ The private member data I'm trying to access (.mode)`

The class that is being passed in as the template parameter (it's within a unit test file):

```
template <class T>
class RuntimeCmp
{
     public:
        enum cmp_mode { normal, reverse };
     private:
        cmp_mode mode;
     public:
        RuntimeCmp( cmp_mode m = normal ) : mode(m) { }
        bool operator()(T const& t1, T const& t2) const { return mode == normal ? t1 < t2 : t2 < t1; }
        bool operator==( RuntimeCmp const& rc ) { return mode == rc.mode; }
};
```

And an example of how my container is being constructed with the template parameter passed in:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( ut_ctor_compare_passed ) {
     RuntimeCmp<double> rc(RuntimeCmp<double>::reverse);
     square_list<double,RuntimeCmp<double>> s(rc);
     vector<double> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

     for (auto x : data)
          s.insert(x);

      BOOST_CHECK( std::equal( s.begin(), s.end(), data.rbegin() ) );
}
```

I was thinking making it a friend class or something like that? Thanks for the tips!

Comment: If `RuntimeCmp` wants to grant `square_list` access to its private members, it could declare it a `friend`.

Comment: Lets say, I can't change the way RuntimeCmp is. I have to make it be able to access or change that data in some way. Would I have to change the way my template parameter is being passed in? Perhaps passing in an enum value or an int?

Comment: If you can't change `RuntimeCmp`, you are sadly out of luck. I presume `mode` is made private for a reason - precisely so that other pieces of code couldn't access it. Ask the author of `RuntimeCmp` to reconsider, or find a way to manage without.

Comment: Not even if I change my template parameter from a class to something else? There has to be a way of doing it..

Comment: If there were a way to access private members from outside their class (without said class cooperating), then they wouldn't be very private, now would they? With all due respect, you engage in wishful thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this link:
https://github.com/altamic/privablic

Also passing private member as template parameter is allowed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless